# Only keep one instance of recurring tasks

Tags: thunderbird

Assume I add a recurring task in Thunderbird/Lightning, like "Water the plants". If I don't mark this task as completed until the next recurrence, Thunderbird will show multiple instances of the task.

Is there a way to make Thunderbird not add another instance to the task list if the previous instance has not been marked as completed?